# Firebase .setvalue not uploading

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 19 textfields that I want to upload to firebase database. At first I wrote this `ref.child("Coupons").child(self.countyyryr.text!).child(self.childx.text!).setValue(["company name" : self.companyname.text, "category" : self.category.text, "email" : self.email.text, "phonenumber" : self.phonenumber.text, "hours" : self.hours.text, "logo" : self.logo.text, "yelplink" : self.yelplink.text, "totaloffer" : self.totaloffer.text, "cp0name" : self.cp0name.text, "cp0code" : self.cp0code.text, "cp0amount" : self.cp0amount.text, "cp0picture" : self.cp0picture.text, "cp1name" : self.cp1name.text, "cp1code" : self.cp1code.text, "cp1amount" : self.cp1amount.text, "cp1picture" : self.cp1picture.text])`

and xcode was stuck indexing. I then separated the upload function into two:

```
ref.child("Coupons").child(self.countyyryr.text!).child(self.childx.text!).setValue(["company name" : self.companyname.text, "category" : self.category.text, "email" : self.email.text, "phonenumber" : self.phonenumber.text, "hours" : self.hours.text, "logo" : self.logo.text, "yelplink" : self.yelplink.text, "totaloffer" : self.totaloffer.text])

ref.child("Coupons").child(self.countyyryr.text!).child(self.childx.text!).setValue([""cp0name" : self.cp0name.text, "cp0code" : self.cp0code.text, "cp0amount" : self.cp0amount.text, cp0picture" : self.cp0picture.text, "cp1name" : self.cp1name.text, "cp1code" : self.cp1code.text, "cp1amount" : self.cp1amount.text, "cp1picture" : self.cp1picture.text])
```

and only the second function was uploading. I tried adding a delay to see if the internet connect was a problem but, the second function was still the only one uploading. I then tried making 3 different functions but now none of them are uploading. Below is my current code, any help is appreciated.

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseDatabase

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    class admi: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var companyname: UITextF

ield!

   @IBOutlet weak var category: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var phonenumber: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var hours: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var logo: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var yelplink: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var totaloffer: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var address0: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var childx: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var cp0name: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var cp0code: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var cp0amount: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var cp0picture: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var cp1name: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var cp1code: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var cp1amount: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var cp1picture: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var countyyryr: UITextField!
   @IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
   ref = Database.database().reference()
    print(companyname.text!, category.text!, email.text!, phonenumber.text!, hours.text!, logo.text!)
    print(yelplink.text!, totaloffer.text!, address0.text!, childx.text!, cp0name.text!, cp0code.text!, cp0amount.text!)
    print(cp0picture.text!, cp1name.text!, cp1code.text!, cp1amount.text!, cp1picture.text!)
    uplo()
    sed()
    dod()

    delay(8) {
    self.companyname.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.category.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.email.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.phonenumber.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.hours.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.logo.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.yelplink.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.totaloffer.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.address0.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.childx.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.cp0name.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.cp0code.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.cp0amount.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.cp0picture.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.cp1name.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.cp1code.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.cp1amount.textColor = UIColor.green
    self.cp1picture.textColor = UIColor.green
    }

    delay(20){
        self.companyname.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.category.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.email.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.phonenumber.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.hours.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.logo.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.yelplink.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.totaloffer.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.address0.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.childx.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.cp0name.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.cp0code.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.cp0amount.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.cp0picture.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.cp1name.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.cp1code.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.cp1amount.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.cp1picture.textColor = UIColor.black

        self.companyname.text = ""
        self.category.text = ""
        self.email.text = ""
        self.phonenumber.text = ""
        self.hours.text = ""
        self.logo.text = ""
        self.yelplink.text = ""
        self.totaloffer.text = ""
        self.address0.text = ""
        self.childx.text = ""
        self.cp0name.text = ""
        self.cp0code.text = ""
        self.cp0amount.text = ""
        self.cp0picture.text = ""
        self.cp1name.text = ""
        self.cp1code.text = ""
        self.cp1amount.text = ""
        self.cp1picture.text = ""
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    companyname.delegate = self
    category.delegate = self
    email.delegate = self
    phonenumber.delegate = self
    hours.delegate = self
    logo.delegate = self
    yelplink.delegate = self
    totaloffer.delegate = self
    address0.delegate = self
    childx.delegate = self
    cp0name.delegate = self
    cp0code.delegate = self
    cp0amount.delegate = self
    cp0picture.delegate = self
    cp1name.delegate = self
    cp1code.delegate = self
    cp1amount.delegate = self
    cp1picture.delegate = self
    countyyryr.delegate = self
}


func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
func uplo() {
    print("reading one")
   ref.child("Coupons").child(self.countyyryr.text!).child(self.childx.text!).setValue(["company name" : self.companyname.text, "category" : self.category.text, "email" : self.email.text, "phonenumber" : self.phonenumber.text, "hours" : self.hours.text])

}
func sed() {
    print("reading two")
    ref.child("Coupons").child(self.countyyryr.text!).child(self.childx.text!).setValue(["logo" : self.logo.text, "yelplink" : self.yelplink.text, "totaloffer" : self.totaloffer.text, "cp0name" : self.cp0name.text, "cp0code" : self.cp0code.text, "cp0amount" : self.cp0amount.text])

}
func dod() {
    print("reading three")
    ref.child("Coupons").child(self.countyyryr.text!).child(self.childx.text!).setValue(["cp0picture" : self.cp0picture.text, "cp1name" : self.cp1name.text, "cp1code" : self.cp1code.text, "cp1amount" : self.cp1amount.text, "cp1picture" : self.cp1picture.text])

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both functions are executing, but you are overriding the value of the path by setting the value to something else. Either use `.updateChildValues` instead of `setValue` after setting the value of the path, or combine the updates into a single dictionary and set the value all at once.

```
func uplo() {
    print("reading one")
   ref.child("Coupons").child(self.countyyryr.text!).child(self.childx.text!).setValue(["company name" : self.companyname.text, "category" : self.category.text, "email" : self.email.text, "phonenumber" : self.phonenumber.text, "hours" : self.hours.text])

}
func sed() {
    print("reading two")
    ref.child("Coupons").child(self.countyyryr.text!).child(self.childx.text!).updateChildValues(["logo" : self.logo.text, "yelplink" : self.yelplink.text, "totaloffer" : self.totaloffer.text, "cp0name" : self.cp0name.text, "cp0code" : self.cp0code.text, "cp0amount" : self.cp0amount.text])

}
func dod() {
    print("reading three")
    ref.child("Coupons").child(self.countyyryr.text!).child(self.childx.text!).updateChildValues(["cp0picture" : self.cp0picture.text, "cp1name" : self.cp1name.text, "cp1code" : self.cp1code.text, "cp1amount" : self.cp1amount.text, "cp1picture" : self.cp1picture.text])

}
```

See the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write?authuser=0#updating_or_deleting_data).